# Check if all strings in one array are in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

This is for a tic tac toe game. I have an array `board` with nine string elements, and a nested array `WIN_COMBINATIONS` with position combinations from `board`:

```
board = ["X", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [6, 4, 2],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8]
]
```

How do I choose the array combinations from `board` that are all `"X"` or all `"O"` using the combinations found in `WIN_COMBINATIONS`?

For example
     a different board than the one above in which X wins in the right diagonal.

```
board = ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "X", "O"]

#  X | O | X
# ---+---+---
#  O | X | O
# ---+---+---
#  X | X | O

won?(board) #=> [2,4,6]
```

Comment: Please provide the examples of these arrays.

Comment: Give example input-output. Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok added the arrays will add the code I put which is very wrong/bad/beginner-y as you may see :p

Comment: Please make ur question more clear. Give an example if possible.

Comment: @TalC thanks for adding the arrays, but I still don't understand your last sentence. Could you provide the expected output, i.e. the combinations you want to choose?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by `WIN_COMBINATIONS`'s "position combinations" (which is already unclear by itself) being different from `board`? If one is flat and another is nested, in what sense can they have the same structure in the first place? 2. Where are the `"O"`s in your `board`?

Comment: I meant the array is an array of different positions that are winning and if all of them are either X or all O then they are winning.

Comment: 2. Where are the "O"s in your original `board`?

Comment: Also thanks I just put an example now @Stefan.

Comment: @sawa that was just a test example to see if it worked in general I provided another board example later on.

Answer (score 5):

A slight variation of [ndn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34718265/477037):

```
board = %w(X O X
           O X O
           X X O)
WIN_COMBINATIONS.select { |c| board.values_at(*c).join =~ /XXX|OOO/ }
#=> [[6, 4, 2]]
```

Explanation:

- [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) returns all elements for which the block returns `true`.
- [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) returns the values at the specified indices:

  ```
  board.values_at(*[0, 1, 2])
  #=> ["X", "O", "X"]
  ```

  `*` converts the array to an argument list, so the above becomes `values_at(0, 1, 2)`
- [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join) returns a string with the concatenated elements:

  ```
  ["X", "O", "X"].join
  #=> "XOX"
  ```
- [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) checks if the string matches the [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html) `/XXX|OOO/`, i.e. either `XXX` or `OOO`

You can replace `select` with [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) if you just want to retrieve the first winning combination.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Code incorporates Stefan's suggestion.

Do this once:

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS.each(&:sort!)
```

Then,

```
h = board.each_index.group_by{|i| board[i]}
# => {"X"=>[0, 1, 2], " "=>[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
WIN_COMBINATIONS.find{|a| (h["X"] & a) == a or (h["O"] & a) == a}
# => [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: You might want to explain `&.&`, it's quite new.

Comment: Actually, `&.` is not necessary, because `(nil & a) == a` evaluates to `false == a`

Answer (score 1):

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS.find do |combination|
  values_at_positions = board.values_at(*combination).uniq
  values_at_positions.size == 1 and ['X', 'O'].include?(*values_at_positions)
end # => [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Why `"X"` and `"Y"`?

Comment: A more straight-forwand (and shorter) check would be `values = board.values_at(*combination); values == %w(X X X) || values == %w(O O O)`

Comment: @Stefan, I didn't think it through initially. Now it would be practically copying  your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity (a slightly updated @Stefan’s answer):

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS.index do |wc|
  board.values_at(*wc).join =~ /(?<l>\w)\k<l>\k<l>/
  # or, as suggested by @Stefan: board.values_at(*wc).join =~ /(\w)\1\1/
end
#⇒ 5
```

Here we match the combinations to three same symbols, which is likely the most semantically correct interpretation of tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: I like your regex approach, but I'd use `/(\w)\1\1/`.

Comment: @Stefan Indeed, updated, thanks. I left `index`, though, to make it more flexible (to have a backward connection to `WIN_COMBINATIONS` array, since it probably makes it easier to debug the wrong values there.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def won?(board)
    xpos = []
    opos = []
    who_won = nil;
    board.each_with_index{|x,i| xpos << i if x == "X" }
    board.each_with_index{|x,i| xpos << i if x == "O" }
    WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |com|
         temp = com & xpos
         who_won = "X" if temp == com
         temp = com & opos
         who_won = "O" if temp == com
         break if !who_won.nil?
    end
    return who_won
end

won?(board) #=> X if x wins, O if O wins. nil if no body wins.
```

Its untested but should work.

Comment: `won?` doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: need to pass the board.

Comment: @Stefan i missed return statement.

Comment: @Stefan But i really like your answer. its really short and sweet.